# How to use \title variable inside a class?

Tags: document-classes

I try to define a class by myself and I want to put title to top-center of page but when I use it like

```
\chead{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{ {\fontfamily{phv} \selectfont \@title}}}}
```

it does not print title to its position.

I use `\maketitle` command in document. I read it that it locks the variable.
So how could I create my class so that it will print the title to page's top-center as a variable?

**EDIT:Changed document class from article to report and it is solved.**

Comment: You could use `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd\maketitle{\global\let\@title\@empty}{}{}{}` to keep the definition of `\@title` after `\maketitle` in `article`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and edit for results

Answer (score 1):

As @Skillmon says, when you use `\maketitle`, `\global\let\@title\@empty` is executed. So you can use `etoolbox` package,

```tex
\patchcmd\maketitle{\global\let\@title\@empty}{}{}{}
```

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle{\global\let\@title\@empty}{}{}{}
\chead{\textcolor{blue}{\ttfamily\@title}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed document class from article to report and it is solved. If is there any solution for article class it is welcome.